# google colab: ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'X' after cloning module from github

Tags: python, machine-learning, module, google-colaboratory, git-clone

I am trying to use code from a github repository, in may case I used:

```
!git clone https://github.com/facebookresearch/MaskFormer.git
```

then in order to ru:

```
!python MaskFormer/demo/demo.py --config-file ../configs/ade20k-150/maskformer_R50_bs16_160k.yaml --input input1.jpg input2.jpg [--other-options] --opts MODEL.WEIGHTS /path/to/checkpoint_file
```

(with the all the needed arguments)
but got this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "MaskFormer/demo/demo.py", line 21, in <module>
    from detectron2.config import get_cfg
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'detectron2'
```

This error occurs with every repository I clone to colab.

What is the correct way to include all modules in the repository?

(I tried mounting the drive but it didn't work)

Comment: try `pip install git+https://github.com/facebookresearch/MaskFormer.git`

Comment: Did you notice that the error is about detectron2 and not the MaskFormer repo  you installed?

Comment: You might want to follow the [installation instructions](https://github.com/facebookresearch/MaskFormer/blob/main/INSTALL.md)

Comment: It means that you have not installed the module. you have to install the modules using `pip install -r requirements.txt`